# R - Create New Column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
X1
House-US
House-FR
FR-FR
US-US
FR-US
```

I would like to create a second column such that:

```
X1       X2
House-US House 
House-FR House
FR-FR    Ia
US-US    Ia
FR-US    Ir
```

If a row starts with House then X2 equal to House, If a row has left equal to right (FR-FR) then X2 equal to Ia and Else X2 equal to Ir.

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
splitdf <- dt[, X1] %>% strsplit("-") %>% unlist %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = T) %>% data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(splitdf) <- c("L", "R")
dt$X2 <- ifelse(splitdf[, "L"] == "House", "House", 
                ifelse(splitdf[, "L"] == splitdf[, "R"], "Ia", "Ir"))
```

Comment: Finally I have done something like: `left_right<-data.frame(str_split_fixed(as.character(dt$X1), "-", 2)) left_right$FLOW_CAT<-ifelse(left_right$x1=="Dom", "Dom",ifelse(as.character(left_right$x1)==as.character(left_right$x2), "Intra", "Inter"))`